# Laravel Octane stopped project from working

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I installed the Laravel octane on Sail and the browser stopped working, when I checked the log of the app container I faced these errors:

```
INFO  Server running…
Local: http://0.0.0.0:9192
Press Ctrl+C to stop the server

WARN  unable to get instance ID; storage clean stamps will be incomplete
ERROR  could not clean default/global storage
ERROR  unable to create folder for config autosave
```

What is the reason? I did not have this kind of problem on Linux.

Comment: more likely a permission issue.

Comment: I changed permissions from sail bash and restarted the service but have same problem @silver

Comment: Double-check that your ports are correctly mapped, as the actual Octane port itself doesn't matter much because of the way things are proxied from the public container to Octane's port. The default ports for Sail is `80` and Octane port is `8000`, so you should still go to the default `80` port in your browser and the request will be internally proxied to Octane within the container, attempting to go to port `8000` won't get you anywhere because that port is not exposed by Docker.

Comment: Alternatively, when I run into these strange errors I typically resolve to resetting the docker containers and it usually fixes the problem. Try `sail down -v` (this will stop all of the containers and destroy any of the associated images, and networks related to your containers including your databases which you will need to migrate and reseed) then use `sail build --no-cache` followed by `sail up` or `sail up -d`. This has nearly always solved those strange conflicts or issues.